# Pulse transit time values (PTT)

Tags: mimic-iii

It seems that PTT based on the ABP & ECG signals is ~300 ms, but when based on the PPG signal then PTT is ~550 ms (consistent for multiple subjects). As I understand both ABP and PPG were measured on the arm. Do you have any idea PTT varies so much?

Answer (score 3):

I will assume you are using the MIMIC-II v3 Waveform database.

If you look at [section 5.4 of the MIMIC-II user guide (warning, 2.3 MB PDF)](https://mimic.physionet.org/archive/mimic-ii-guide.pdf), you will see the following:

> **Inter-waveform alignment problems.** The method used for MIMIC
>   waveform data extraction was not designed for inter-waveform
>   analysis. The waveform data contain unspecified/unknown filtering
>   delays and/or unknown inter-channel delays, which may not be
>   constant in a given record. Therefore, although the ECGs are
>   time-aligned, there may be a (changing) delay of up to 500ms between
>   any of the other waveforms in the data. Therefore, no pulse transit
>   times can be accepted to be true (absolute or relative).

It's worth noting that the 500ms number is probably a conservative estimate.